# jboss fuse 6.1 features:addurl TLS1.2 Failed due to javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java-7, tls1.2, jboss6.x, sslhandshakeexception

We are in process to migrate a new nexus repo.
The below are the platform information:

```
   Nexus Repo Server:   HTTPS only supports TLS 1.2
   Application server:  FUSE 6.1
                        Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_141-b31)
                        Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.141-b31, mixed mode)
```

However, when we run karaf command "features:addurl <...> ", we are keeping getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure.

We have set the following JVM options:

```
            -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="<....>"
            -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="<...>"
            -Djavax.net.debug=all
            -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
            -Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved and we need to add the following JVM option to resolve SSL Handshake exception:

```sh
-Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```